# JS формирование страници

Tags: javascript, jquery

Все доброго времени суток. 
Правильно ли я делаю. 
есть серв  по  Ajax  идет запрос  получаем  json Ответ массив в 500 строк 
их нужно открисовать  на клиенте .
в  js  через  for  формирую  html   и  вставляю

```
$('#myBlock').html(html);
```

Вернали данная логика .  также требуется делать  модификацию выдачи  сортировка груперовка.
мало опыта в  js - не доконца понимаю правильно-ли  это все делать на клиенте .
Поделитесь опытом .

Comment: есть определенные шаблонизаторы, попробуйте их в деле. По вашему вопросу вам нужно лишь отрисовывать то, что вы хотите из приходящих данных.

Comment: Хотелось бы  без шаблонизаторов . сортировка групировка  будут реализоватся в  цикле  ( впорос в том  модификацию массива   делать  на стороне клиента ) или делать доплнительный запрос  в бек и от туда получать разные массивы .  в зависимости от  требуемых условий.

Comment: Если объемы данных большие, все лучше делать на сервере, и по необходимым фильтрам возвращать нужный набор.

Comment: Сортировки и фильтры вернее делать на сервере. Потому что где сортировки и фильтры - там и паджинация. То есть у вас 1000 записей, вы хотите сделать страницы по 10 записей и получить 13 страницу. Если все делать на клиенте, то вам придется получать 1000 записей чтобы все отсортировать сгруппировать и решить - какая страница 13я. А если делать это  на сервере то такой проблемы не возникает.

Comment: Расскажите это авторам bootstrap tables.  Про сортировку, пагинацию и прочее. Делают же